# How do I split on multiple conditions in string? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

How do I get given value?

```
name // google
index // 0
LastName //Last Name
```

My approach is not working because I have a singular condition '.'

```
value = '#[pill(google.0.LastName)]'
const [name, index, name] = value.split('.')
```

Regex is `/#\[pill\((.*?)\)\]/gi`

Comment: Regexp find the text inside `()` before splitting on a `.`

Comment: can you provide an example in the answer? I added Regex pattern

Comment: yeap; added the variable before that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forgo the split using three matching expressions in your regex like this
,
`#\[pill\((.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\)\]`

```js
var string = "#[pill(google.0.LastName)]"
var [_, name, Index, LastName] = string.match(/#\[pill\((.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\)\]/)

console.log(name, Index, LastName)
```

Comment: can you provide a working example? It doesn't work on my end

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = '#[pill(google.0.LastName)]';

console.log(
  test.substring(test.indexOf('(') + 1, test.indexOf(')')).split('.')
);

console.log(
  test.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split('.')
);
```

Here are a couple different ways; one with substring and one with a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the parts of the matched string.

```js
const
    string = '#[pill(google.0.LastName)]',
    [firstName, index, lastName] = string.match(/[^\(]+(?=\))/)[0].split('.');
    

console.log(firstName);
console.log(index);
console.log(lastName);
```